# Полноценный калькулятор на с++

Tags: c++

Помогите. Мне нужно сделать полноценный консольный калькулятор который понимает что хочет пользователь. Допустим Пользователь вводит: ((2+4-6)/5)^2 или 2*10/5 или (sqrt(2))^2 и выводился ответ. Я знаю сделать калькулятор на определённое количество символов но как сделать его большим разным количеством?

Comment: Вам тут не помогут с нуля составить программу. Советую найти в интернете исходный код готового калькулятора и покопаться в нём, понять как он работает

Comment: В книге Яцека Головица с++17 есть реализация того, что Вам нужно. Решение построенно на обратной польской нотации. Страницу я думаю найдёте сами....

Comment: Главное, когда будешь всё это делать, не забудь реализовать таблицу приоритетов операций, а то у тебя сложение или вычитание будут выполняться раньше, чем умножение и деление. Еще нужно скобки реализовать для того, чтобы этот приоритет пользователь мог менять. Это не так просто.

Comment: Читайте про [shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) и [обратную польскую нотацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)...

Answer (score 2):

Сперва изучите работу с символами и строками. Потом вы должны разделить строку и проанализировать, тем самым узнать какое действие выполнить первым, какое дальше, есть ли там скобки, если есть то его отдельно решить и так далее или работатьс двумя переменными, отправляя их в созданный метод, тем самым обратно получая ответ

Comment: Я не понимаю. Кто тут сидит и всех минусит? Какой-то злодей...

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον А я не понимаю, кто поставил аж три плюса. В ответе никакой полезной информации, только общие слова.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я поставил, чтобы восстановить справедливость =) Зачем минусовать то? Нормальный ответ. Не нравится - проигнорь.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον коков вопрос - таков ответ

Comment: @Παν μέτρον άριστον, вы правы в том, что есть такие люди, которые просто минусуют, но я категорически не согласен с тем, что нужно проигнорировать тогда, когда считаешь ответ не полезным(ответ не нравится). Проигнорирование означает пассивность, а если вы пользуетесь сайтом, лучше быть активным(всегда нужно стараться делать хорошо, в обратном случаи незачем делать...).  Ставьте свои плюсы и минусы активнее, но только  чтобы было все обосновано, а не с придирками на  опечатки или упущения(в таких случаях в комментах просто предупреждать). Я согласен с HolyBlackCat

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, если комментарий нейтральный (не особо полезный, но и не неверный), то и минусовать его незачем. Этот именно такой, я считаю.

Comment: @Παν μέτρον άριστον, а вы представьте себе, что вы сами ищете по инету ответ на такой вопрос и  читаете такой ответ. Что он вам даст? Тут главное не только отвечать ТС, а отвечать так, чтобы было полезно и для других участников. Если нет, то нужно минусовать, чтобы ответ был проигнорирован  другими пользовательями. Минус это не наказание и ничем не вредит автору, но вредить сайту и его пользовательям может, если не обоснован...(Я так понимаю)

Comment: Вообше вопрос такой, что стоит его закрыть по причине, что он слышком общий, и лично я  проголосую именно за это.